# javascript one object method via other javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var s = {

    fname:'Ashish',

    lname:'Gokhale',

    getFullName: function(){
        return this.fname +' '+ this.lname;
    }

}

var p = {fname: "Xyz", lname: "Abc"};
```

Above are my two  javascript object.

I want full name with p's variable without copying the data from any object.

I want this in a way that both object will retain there original value what they currently have.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  You want to extract data from `p`; then what's the relevance of `s`?

Comment: Your syntax is erroneous. `getFullName(){` should be `getFullName: function(){`

Comment: `var s = {

    fname:'Ashish',

    lname:'Gokhale',

    getFullName:function(){
        return this.fname +' '+ this.lname;
    }

}

var p = {fname: "Xyz", lname: "Abc"};
s.fname=p.fname;
s.lname=p.lname;
console.log(s.getFullName());`

Comment: Yes it should be in a way getFullName : function(){}, but what mainly I want is, I want to use getFullName for p varriable:

it should return me Xyz Abc, without copying method from one varriable to other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)** to merge the array, which updates the two properties.

```js
var s = {
  fname: 'Ashish',
  lname: 'Gokhale',
  getFullName: function() {
    return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
  }
}
var p = {
  fname: "Xyz",
  lname: "Abc"
};

Object.assign(s, p);

console.log(s.getFullName());
```

---

**UPDATE :** In case if you don't want to update the original object then you can generate a new object with it by passing an empty object as first parameter.

```js
var s = {
  fname: 'Ashish',
  lname: 'Gokhale',
  getFullName: function() {
    return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
  }
}
var p = {
  fname: "Xyz",
  lname: "Abc"
};

console.log(Object.assign({}, s, p).getFullName());
```

---

For older browser check [polyfill option of the method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill).

---

Another option that you can use is `bind()` method, which helps to update the `this` keyword value, set `p` as this argument in **[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)**.

```js
var s = {
  fname: 'Ashish',
  lname: 'Gokhale',
  getFullName: function() {
    return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
  }
}
var p = {
  fname: "Xyz",
  lname: "Abc"
};

var fn = s.getFullName.bind(p);

console.log(fn());
```

Comment: Now s has lose its definition, the case is this I have to retain definition of variables

I can not assign it to temporary variable, It was an interview question in cognizant.

Comment: @Ashish :  added last method using bind, which may help you

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot

Comment: @Ashish :  glad to help you :)